# Grep lines listed in one file from another file and then print the sequence above

Tags: python, bash, unix

I have two files, FileA and File B. File A contains all of the data. File B contains the sequences of interest that I want to find in File A. The actual files I'm working with have over 6000 lines in them.

File A:

```
Name1  
Apples  
Name2  
Pears  
Name3  
Pears   
Name4   
Grapes   
Name5    
Apples
```

File B :

```
Apples    
Pears
```

I want to write a unix command or python script that will allow me to print only the line above the sequences of interest.

I have tried using this command:

```
grep -B 1 -f FileB FileA | awk -F '\n' 'ln ~ /^$/ { ln = "matched"; print $1 } $1 ~ /^--$/ { ln = "" }'
```

but I get the below list without any way to differentiate between the names for apples and pears

```
Name1   
Name5     
Name2  
Name3
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
Apples       
Name1    
Name5    
Pears   
Name2    
Name3
```

I then need this list to become something like this:

```
Apples >Name 1, Name 5   
Pear > Name 2, Name 3
```

I'm very new to programming and any advice would be great!

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question: the grep part of your command works just fine. It's the `awk` command that doesn't do what you expect. In fact, looking at what your want the final output to be, I wouldn't even bother with `grep` or `awk`, I'd go right to Python and its [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) library.

Comment: In the **awk** script, you simply neglected to print out the fruit name that triggered the print.  As for Python, you haven't made any attempt whatsoever, so we can't help you  with your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input *FileA*, some `sed` code transforms the stream into a `fruit Name#N` format, then [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) to collapse it on field #2, and a `grep` to output only the desired lines:

```
sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/ /p' < FileA | datamash -W -s -g1 collapse 2 | grep -f FileB
```

Output:

```
Apples  Name1,Name5
Pears   Name2,Name3
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I had to change the command a bit as it was printing out half of the names due to spaces in between but that worked really well! Thanks!

Comment: @Ellie, Please have a look at:  [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/334345)   I'd also noticed trailing spaces in the OP data, but wasn't certain whether those belonged in the original data or not, and therefore removed those spaces before answering.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat B.txt | xargs -III  sh -c \
               'echo II  "\> "; grep II A.txt -B1 | grep -v "\-\-" | grep -v II '
```

Does the job.

> Apples
>
> Name1
>
> Name5
>
> Pears
>
> Name2
>
> Name3

After that you can separate the name from the number with a `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you are already familiar with awk, why not to try a simple awk snippet for the whole job:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=(!a[$1]?prev:a[$1]", "prev);prev=$1;next}$1 in a{print $1" > "a[$1]}' fileA fileB
Apples > Name1, Name5
Pears > Name2, Name3
```

Let me know if you need to explain this snippet in details.